The number of distinct digits in the product $AB$ in its decimal expansion

The integer $A$ consists of $666$ threes, and the integer $B$ consists of $666$ sixes. The number of distinct digits in the product $AB$ in its decimal expansion is $X$. Find $X$


$AB=33...3 × 66...6= 3[11...1]×6[11...1]=18[11...1]^2$ where there are $666$ $1$'s but how to determine which digits don't appear in the expansion? Help

$33 \times 66 = 2178$, then $333 \times 666 = 221778$, then $3333 \times 6666 = 22217778$...

What's the source of this question?

@BrianMoehring It came in our class test

And your class is... an introduction to number theory?  (your question feels a bit more like a high school contest problem like you'd find on the AMC10/12, if I'm frank)

You can formally solve this by writing
$$\begin{align*}33\ldots3 \times 66\ldots6
 &= 18\left(\frac{10^{666}-1}9\right)^2 \\
 &= \frac29\left(10^{1332}-2\times 10^{666} + 1\right) \\
 &= \left(2\times \frac{10^{665}-1}9\times 10^{667}\right) + 10^{666} + \left(7 \times \frac{10^{665}-1}9 \times 10\right) + 8.\end{align*}$$
Then it's just some accounting to see that each of the $1332$ digits is given by exactly one of the terms, so we can read off the unique digits: $2, 1, 7, 8$.
That is, the answer is either four or five, depending on whether we ignore or include, respectively, leading zeros.

+1, though not sure why we’d include leading zeros
